# Plot SNP density for multiple samples using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, bioinformatics

**EDITED**

Hello

I want to create a python program that take as input: the `FCV file`, `window` and `increment value` and return a **plot** with **SNP density** in each window for all samples (columns). **Example image bellow.**

The steps I wish to take:

1. Establish a window of X bases wide and count the number of
   polymorphisms in that window
2. Record the polymorphism count and the start position of the of window
3. Shift the window down the chromosome by Y bases, count the number of polymorphisms in the window. You will be counting many of the same polymorphisms you counted in the previous window.
4. Record the polymorphism count and the current start position of the window
5. Continue moving the window down the chromosome by Y bases, counting the polymorphisms, and recording the count and position data until your window reaches the end of the chromosome
6. Do this for all of the individuals in the dataframe
7. Create a line or scatter graph of the (count, position) data for each individual. The graph should present one line for each individual

I can do it using R/Bioconductor pachages or Biopython, but I need a basic python solution.
Any help please!
Thanks

Here's what I tried: [VCFfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WRXBzBw6F51-eH5PSTShbRMOjo3CZZqh/view?usp=sharing)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# libraries
import argparse
import io
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

    ## Read VCF file
# Read vcf file without headers
def read_vcf(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
        dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
               'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
        sep='\t'
    ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})

df = read_vcf('VCFFile.vcf')

# cleaning data
## format CHROM column
df['CHROM'] = df['CHROM'].str.replace('chr0','').astype(int)

## select useful columns: all columns except not useful ones
df = df[df.columns.difference(['ID', 'INFO', 'REF', 'ALT', 'QUAL', 'FILTER', 'FORMAT'])]

# Get alleles for each sample
def get_alleles(df):
    for i in df.columns.difference(['CHROM', 'POS']):
        suffix=  str(i) + '_genotype'
        df[suffix] = df[str(i)].astype(str).str[0:3]
        #df.drop(str(i), axis=1)
        #df = df[df.columns.drop(str(i))]
# apply the function
get_alleles(df)

# remove original genotype columns
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.endswith('genotype')]
filter_col.append('CHROM')
filter_col.append('POS')

df = df[filter_col]

# replace genotypes: 1/1 by 1, else by 0
list_values = ['0/0', './.', './0', '0/.', '1/0', '0/1']
df = df.replace(to_replace =list_values, value ='NaN')
df = df.replace(to_replace ='1/1', value =1)
```

Now I want to plot SNP density for each sample:

```
# plot SNP density for each sample ==========================================
# get data for each sample
# create a function to select columns
def select_sample(col):
    x = df[['POS', str(col)]]
    #remove NaN
    x = x[x[str(col)] ==1]
    return x

sample_1 = select_sample("A_genotype")
sample_2 = select_sample("B_genotype")
sample_3 = select_sample("C_genotype")
sample_4 = select_sample("D_genotype")
sample_5 = select_sample("E_genotype")
sample_6 = select_sample("F_genotype")
sample_7 = select_sample("I_genotype")
sample_8 = select_sample("P_genotype")
```

I can't add incrementValue to get a figure like below [image: figure like below].Figure 1 – Polymorphism density plot using a window size of 1,000,000 with an increment of 100,000

```
def plot_windowed_variant_density(pos, window_size, incrementValue=None, title, ax):

    # setup windows 
    bins = np.arange(0, pos.max(), window_size)
    print(bins)
    
    #incrementValue
    #incrementValue = ???????????
    
    # use window midpoints as x coordinate
    x = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2
    
    # compute variant density in each window
    count, _ = np.histogram(sample['POS'], bins=bins)
    y= count
    # plot
    sns.despine(ax=ax, offset=10)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_xlabel('Chromosome position (Mb)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Count')
    if title:
        ax.set_title(title)
#====================================================

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
# Apply the function: 
for i in [sample_1, sample_2, sample_3, sample_4, sample_5, sample_6, sample_7, sample_8]:
    plot_windowed_variant_density(i.POS, 1000000,'test', ax)
```

Comment: I can't answer this question because it is getting more and more technical, but I think the loop processing of the sample data frame will be in the form of adding the next loop with the following code that calculates the number of bins and handles the x-axis restriction, and then executing the current function.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the ax of the graph to the function argument, you can create an overlay on the same graph.

```
# plot SNP density ==========================================
def plot_windowed_variant_density(pos, window_size, title, ax):

    # setup windows 
    bins = np.arange(0, pos.max(), window_size)

    # use window midpoints as x coordinate
    x = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2
    
    # compute variant density in each window
    count, _ = np.histogram(pos, bins=bins)

    y= count

    # plot
    sns.despine(ax=ax, offset=10)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_xlabel('Chromosome position (Mb)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Count')
    if title:
        ax.set_title(title)
#====================================================

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3))
# Apply the function: I can use a for loop
for i in [sample_1,sample_2,sample_3]:
    plot_windowed_variant_density(i.POS, 1000000,'test', ax)
    #plot_windowed_variant_density(sample_2.POS, 1000000,'test', ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I am still missing an important step. I want to calculate the number of SNPs in each window with a sliding of 10 000 bp each time, that is to say: take a window of size 1 Mb, calculate the number of SNPs, make a step of 10 000 bp and recalculate the number of SNPs in the new window .... until the end of the chromosome.

Comment: I understand that the question is about displaying multiple lines on the same graph, and I am working on the code. I am not a gene-related person at all, so I don't understand your comment. Can you please edit the question or something?

Comment: I edited the whole script. I hope it is clear. Thank you